# Error getting the number version of a directory name

Tags: c#, linq, compiler-errors, version

I made a code to get the version number of a directory name for example this folder named Update5.0.1 I just need the "5.0.1" part. I pass the directory path to this function:

```
public int CompareVersion(string NovoUpdate, string Config)
{
      int Status = 0;
      try
      {
          ExeConfigurationFileMap configOld = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();
          configOld.ExeConfigFilename = Config;
          Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(configOld, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
          if (config.AppSettings.Settings["Version"] != null)
          {
              string value = config.AppSettings.Settings["Version"].Value.ToString();
              Version ver = Version.Parse(value);
              Version version = null;
              Version VersionFinal = null;
              var lastVersion = new DirectoryInfo(NovoUpdate).FullName;
        //.Where(d => d.Name.StartsWith("UPDATE_"))
        .Select(d => new { Directory = d, Token = d.Name.Split('_') })
        .Where(x => x.Token.Length == 3 && Version.TryParse(x.Token[2], out version))
        .Select(x => new { x.Directory, Date = x.Token[1], Version = version })
        .OrderByDescending(x => x.Version)
        .FirstOrDefault();
              if (lastVersion != null)
              {
                  VersionFinal = Version.Parse(lastVersion.ToString());
              }

              if (ver >= VersionFinal)
                  Status = 1;
              else
                  Status = 0;
          }
          else Status = -1;
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
          Erro NovoErro = new Erro();
          Program.Erro = ex.ToString();
          NovoErro.ShowDialog();
      }
      return Status;
 }
```

> I have an error on this line:

```
var lastVersion = new DirectoryInfo(NovoUpdate);
            //.Where(d => d.Name.StartsWith("UPDATE_"))
            .Select(d => new { Directory = d, Token = d.Name.Split('_') })
```

> I've alredy tried to change the "lastVersion" to string or just use
>   the "NovoUpdate" string instead of DirectoryInfo. I dont really know
>   how to use linq Any help would be aprecciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the final fully working code:

```
public int CompareVersion(string NovoUpdate, string Config, bool ServiceChanged)
        {
            Global.Erro = "";
            Global.ErroGrave = false;
            int Status = 0;
                ExeConfigurationFileMap configOld = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();
                configOld.ExeConfigFilename = Config;
                Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(configOld, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
            if (config.AppSettings.Settings["Version"] != null)
            {
                string value = config.AppSettings.Settings["Version"].Value.ToString();
                Version ver = Version.Parse(value);
                Version versione = null;
                if (System.IO.Path.GetFileName(NovoUpdate).ToLower() == "orcaservice")
                {
                    string name2 = Directory.GetParent(NovoUpdate).ToString();
                    string Versionn = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(name2);
                    string[] Versions2 = Versionn.Split('_');
                    Version.TryParse(Versions2[2], out versione);
                }
                else
                {


                }
                if (ver < versione)
                    Status = 1;
                else
                    Status = 0;
            }

            else Status = -1;




            return Status;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot  to call "*GetDirectories*" method, like:

`new DirectoryInfo(NovoUpdate).GetDirectories().Select...`

Comment: but .GetDirectories will enumerate all directories within "NovoUpdate" directory. I just need to check the version of the current directory wich path is on "NovoUpdate" var

Answer (score 0):

You don't need Linq if you just want to extract version from the directory name.

Try

```
string path = @"C:\Path\Update5.0.1";
string name = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(path);
string match = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(name, @"\d\.\d\.\d");
string version = match.Value;
```

You'll get "5.0.1"

Comment: the folder is name like this "UPDATE_20080311_5.0.0" your code just returs "20080"

Comment: yes, my bad. see updated 3rd line (with \. instead of just .)